# logstash with date specific file names

Tags: logstash

I have an app that writes logs like

```
access_log-2014-09-08
access_log-2014-09-09
access_log-2014-09-10
```

It seems that if I have a input=>file=>path defined for access_log* it only works on what files are there when it started up. When midnight rolls around, and it makes a new file, logstash doesn't see it.  Is there a way to specify a path that will catch this?  Also I don't need it tailing anything except for the current day. It's not a huge problem if it looks at everything but it would be cleaner and nice to not do that.

Logstash config:

```
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/var/log/apache/access_log-*" ]
  }
... filters and output ...
}
```

Comment: OS?  Can you show your actual config for that input portion?

Comment: I'll edit it in.... it's RHEL but that doesn't matter.

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior.  I created an almost identical config file, started logstash and created a new logfile with something in it and it picked it up after about 15 seconds, so either you need to add `start_position => beginning` to your file input or do more debugging.  `bin/logstash agent --debug` is your friend for diagnosing things like this.

Comment: I confirm Alcanzar's comment, the file module with globing is checking for new files every n seconds.